# If then else in dplyr package

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

What is the logic to use for an 'if then else' in `dplyr`?
If I want to say, 'if `x` is greater than `y`, return `1`' I would do this.

```
newdf<- df %>% mutate(newvar = case_when(x > y ~ 1))
```

I want to say, if `x` is greater than `y`, return `1`, else `0`.
How do I write this?

Comment: You don't need any if/else or case_when i.e. `df %>% mutate(newvar = as.integer(x > y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use :

```
newdf = df %>% mutate(newvar = ifelse(x > y, 1, 0))
```

Or using case_when :

```
newdf = df %>% mutate(newvar = case_when(x > y ~ 1, x <= y ~0))
#or
newdf = df %>% mutate(newvar = case_when(x > y ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
```

The TRUE condition used in a case_when refers to all element that are FALSE in the previous conditions.

Comment: to be fully `tidyverse` you should be using `if_else`